# Approximate Match Without Sorting

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of dates in column A sorted in ascending order.  Cell C1 contains a date.  I want a formula to find the earliest date in column A that is equal to or greater than the date in C1.

I realize this can be done by sorting column A in descending order and using the following formula...

```
=MATCH(C1,A:A,-1)
```

...but curiosity has me wondering if it's possible without changing the sort order.  The formula above returned an error when the worksheet was sorted in ascending order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1,A:A,0)),MATCH(C1,A:A,0),MATCH(C1,A:A)+1)
```

It test whether there is an exact match, if so it uses the exact match.  Otherwise it uses the default and then moves down one row.

Or simplified:

```
=MATCH(C1,A:A)+IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1,A:A,0)),0,1)
```

Or even simpler:

```
=MATCH(C1,A:A)+ISERROR(MATCH(C1,A:A,0))
```

[image]

Comment: This did the trick!  I also upvoted the answer from @seb because he answered my question as originally asked.  I didn't mention the header I used in cell A1.  This formula finds the correct row whether a header is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is sorted in ascending order, you can use a countif

```
=countif(A:A, "<" & C1)
```

just be sure your data is always sorted and the header may need to be added manually if it is text.

Comment: You will need to Add 1 to get row in which the date `is equal to or greater than the date in C1.`  And also add 1 for each title rows that may exist.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.  I won't edit the answer to keep it simple but you are right.  Regards

Comment: OP need to know the `COUNTIF` will need much more processing power too

Comment: Or `=COUNTIF(A:A, "<" & C1)+MATCH(MIN(A:A),A:A,0)` which will find the first date on the list and add that.  So regardless of which row the dates start it will return the actual row number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
=MAXIFS(A:A,A:A,"<="&C1)
```

to identify the closest date